# Looping over multiple files using a multi input algorithm with three digit numbers in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am using a genetic interpretation software called SAIGE-GENE. The algorithm looks like this (full algorithm at https://github.com/weizhouUMICH/SAIGE/wiki/Genetic-association-tests-using-SAIGE#step-2--performing-the-region--or-gene-based-association-tests): It involves multiple different files being entered with chromosome numbers in their file names (1 to 22).

```
SPAGMMATtest = function(
         vcfFile = "",
                 vcfFileIndex = "",
         vcfField = "DS",
         groupFile ="",
         savFile = "",
         savFileIndex = "",
         sampleFile = "", 
         idstoExcludeFile = "",
         idstoIncludeFile = "",
         rangestoExcludeFile = "",
         rangestoIncludeFile = "",
         chrom = "",
         start = 1,
         end = 250000000,
         IsDropMissingDosages = FALSE,  
         minMAC = 0.5, 
                 minMAF = 0,
         maxMAFforGroupTest = 0.5,
             minInfo = 0,
                 GMMATmodelFile = "", 
                 varianceRatioFile = "", 
                 SPAcutoff=2, 
                 SAIGEOutputFile = "",
         numLinesOutput = 10000, 
         IsSparse=TRUE,
```

......

I haven't put the whole thing here as it isn't relevant. I am inputting a few different files into this algorithm and normally I name my files chr1_file_name.txt....chr22_file_name.txt.

I then use a for loop in R on the whole algorithm using the paste function to input the different file names by chromosome number:

```
for(i in 1:22){SPAGMMATtest = function(
         vcfFile = paste("chr",i,"_file_name.txt", sep=""),
                 vcfFileIndex = "",
         vcfField = "DS",
         savFile = "",
         groupFile ="paste("chr",i,".group_file.txt", sep="")",
```

etc

This works fine however, I thought I would be clever and use three digit naming for my file names for this experiment: chr001_file_name.txt...chr022_file_name.txt.

My previous loop now does not work and if I change the start of the loop to for(i in 001:022) it doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this without renaming all my files?

Comment: try: `vcfFile = paste("chr",sprintf( "%03d", i),"_file_name.txt", sep=""),`   edit: for shorter code you can use `paste0()`, and drop the sep-argument...

Comment: thanks Wimpel I think that worked (it takes ages to run!). Do you stick for (i in 1:22) in the loop then? Does "%03d" mean one zero and then i to a total of 3 digits?

Comment: `%03d` means: convert to three digits, add leading zero's when needed.. so 1 becomes 001, 21 becomes 021, and 201 stays 201.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wimpel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63449447/looping-over-multiple-files-using-a-multi-input-algorithm-with-three-digit-numbe#comment112196672_63449447) has suggested to

> try: `vcfFile = paste("chr",sprintf( "%03d", i),"_file_name.txt", sep="")`
> , edit: for shorter code you can use `paste0()`, and drop the sep-argument.

in order to create character file names which include 3 digits and leading zeroes, e.g., 001, 002, ..., 022.

This can be further shortened by creating the filename *completely* with `sprintf()` thereby removing the calls to `paste()` or `paste0()`:

```
sprintf("chr%03d_file_name.txt", i)
```

With `i <- 1`, e.g., `sprintf("chr%03d_file_name.txt", i)` returns `"chr001_file_name.txt"`.

---

There is a second observation:

The OP has posted the code snippet

```
for(i in 1:22){SPAGMMATtest = function(
         vcfFile = paste("chr",i,"_file_name.txt", sep=""),
                 vcfFileIndex = "",
         vcfField = "DS",
         savFile = "",
         groupFile ="paste("chr",i,".group_file.txt", sep="")",
         ...
```

This looks like as if the OP has pulled the function *definition* into the `for` loop. I believe it is sufficient only to *call* the function from within the `for` loop:

```
for (i in 1:22) {
     SPAGMMATtest(
         vcfFile = sprintf("chr%03d_file_name.txt", i),
         vcfFileIndex = "",
         vcfField = "DS",
         savFile = "",
         groupFile = sprintf("chr%03d.group_file.txt", i)
         ...
```

Comment: Dear @Uwe, many thanks for taking the time to refine the code and the helpful explanation. Thanks to both your efforts I've learnt a lot about the utility of sprintf and calling for loops more effectively.